# Show that $\varphi_{\epsilon}\to\varphi_{0}$, in the weak topology.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X=C^{1}([-1,1])$ endowed with the norm $\| f\|_{1}=\|f\|_{\infty}+\|f'\|_{\infty}$. We define the functions, $$\varphi_{\epsilon}(f)=\frac{1}{2\epsilon}(f(\epsilon)-f(-\epsilon))\qquad\mbox{and}\qquad \varphi_{0}(f)=f'(0)$$

Show that $\varphi_{\epsilon}\to\varphi_{0}$, $\epsilon\to 0^{+}$, in the weak topology. Is this convergence in the strong topology?

My attemp: If we define $(X,\|\cdot\|_{1})$ is a banach space, and furthermore $\varphi_{\epsilon}$ and $\varphi_{0}$, are linear forms continuous, and  $\|\varphi_{\epsilon}\|\leq1$, for each $0<\epsilon<1$. Can give me some hint, to prove the convergence in the weak topology, thanks!

Comment: MVT says $\lVert \varphi_{\epsilon}\rVert \leqslant 1$. The exact value isn't important.

Comment: @DanielFischer whats means MVT??

Comment: Mean value theorem.

Comment: @DanielFischer why do yo say, the norm is less than 1, throught the MVT??

Comment: What does the mean value theorem state about the quotient $\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}$?

Comment: That is equal to $f'(c)$, with $c\in (a,b)$.

Comment: And therefore, what is $\varphi_{\epsilon}(f)$?

Comment: Will be $f'(\epsilon)$

Comment: Not quite, usually. $f'(c)$ for some $c \in (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$. So $\lvert \varphi_{\epsilon}(f)\rvert \leqslant \lVert f\rVert_1$.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer!

Comment: Isn't the weak convergence obvious? $\phi_\epsilon$ converges to $\phi_0$ weakly if $\phi_\epsilon (f) \to \phi_0(f)$ for all $f\in X$. Writing out this is just the definition of the derivatives.